# Specified Expression not part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT 
    Product_Line_ID=2 OR Product_Line_ID=3, 
    COUNT(Product_Finish), MIN(Standard_Price)
    FROM Product_T 
    WHERE Product_Finish
    GROUP BY Standard_Price
    HAVING AVG(Standard_Price) <700
    ORDER BY Product_FInish;
```

I keep getting this error: Your query does not include the specified expression 'Product_Line_ID=2 OR Product_Line_ID=3' as part of an aggregate function. Can anyone help me with this? Not sure how to select product line id that is 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

What is confusing about the error message?  `Product_Line_ID=2 OR Product_Line_ID=3` is not valid SQL.

Your query basically makes no sense.  You have boolean conditions in the `SELECT`, you have a `WHERE` clause with a column name and no conditions, you are ordering by the column you are counting.

I can guess that you intend something like this:

```
SELECT Product_Line_ID, COUNT(Product_Finish), MIN(Standard_Price)
FROM Product_T 
WHERE Product_Line_ID IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY Product_Line_ID
HAVING AVG(Standard_Price) < 700
ORDER BY COUNT(Product_Finish);
```

Comment: Oh ok not sure why I thought there was an OR statement I could use for that

Comment: @user2304873 `IN` is equivalent to using `OR`. One advantage is that it tends to avoid problems with parentheses and order of precedence along with being shorter and easier to read.